# How to build an Arraylist of objects from toggle OnClickListeners inside RecyclerView Adapter's items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, observer-pattern

I'm building an Android app of media, and trying to add a Playlist feature to it, the user will be able to create a playlist of his own and modify it.

I'm using a RecyclerView to show the user list of songs which he can choose from.
The problem is I don't understand how to pass the Arraylist of chosen songs from the adapter to the fragment.
I've tried to use the Observer pattern but the don't know how to use that information.

This is my Fragment for creating the playlist:

```java
public class CreatePlaylistFragment extends Fragment implements PlaylistAdapterInterface {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_playlist, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<ProgramsData> dataArrayList = ProgramsReceiver.getPrograms();
        ArrayList<ProgramsData> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(dataArrayList);

        adapter = new CreatePlaylistAdapter(dataArrayList, view.getContext(), this);
        adapter.adapterInterface = this;


        ivCreatePlaylist.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Creating Playlist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new PlaylistsJsonWriter(playlistArrayList,getContext()).execute();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void OnItemClicked(ArrayList<ProgramsData> programs) {
        programsToCreate = programs;
        String s = etListName.getText().toString();
        playlistArrayList.add(new Playlist(s, programsToCreate));

    }
}
```

This is the Recycler Adapter with ViewHolder as inner class:

```java
public class CreatePlaylistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CreatePlaylistViewHolder> {

    List<ProgramsData> programsDataList;
    Context context;
    public PlaylistAdapterInterface adapterInterface = null;

    public CreatePlaylistAdapter(List<ProgramsData> programsDataList, Context context , PlaylistAdapterInterface adapterInterface) {
        this.programsDataList = programsDataList;
        this.context = context;
        this.adapterInterface = adapterInterface;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CreatePlaylistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chose_program_to_playlist_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new CreatePlaylistViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CreatePlaylistViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ProgramsData programsData = programsDataList.get(i);

        holder.tvProgramName.setText(programsData.getProgramName());
        if (programsData.getStudentName() != null)
            holder.tvStudentName.setText(programsData.getStudentName());
        else holder.tvLine.setText(""); //if there is no student the line won't be printed

        holder.ivProfilePic.setImageResource(programsData.getProfilePic());
        holder.programsData = programsData;
//        holder.mAdapterInterface = adapterInterface;
        adapterInterface.OnItemClicked(holder.programs);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return programsDataList.size();
    }
}

class CreatePlaylistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvProgramName;
    TextView tvStudentName;
    TextView tvLine;
    CircleImageView ivProfilePic;
    ToggleButton tbCheck;
    ProgramsData programsData;
    ArrayList<ProgramsData> programs;
    PlaylistAdapterInterface mAdapterInterface;


    public CreatePlaylistViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvProgramName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProgramName);
        tvStudentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentName);
        ivProfilePic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic);
        tvLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLine);
        tbCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tbCheck);


        programs= new ArrayList<>();

        tbCheck.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (tbCheck.isChecked()) {
                tbCheck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked);
                programs.add(programsData);
            } else if (!tbCheck.isChecked()) {
                tbCheck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
                programs.remove(programsData);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

And this is the interface for the Observer Pattern:

```java
public interface PlaylistAdapterInterface {
    void OnItemClicked(ArrayList<ProgramsData> programs);
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but I just don't understand how to pass the data from the adapter back to the fragment...

Comment: Whats is the scope of Arraylist of objects? Do you want to access it out side the view holder class

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what are you trying to do.
The code contains several errors that I'll try to explain.

A clear error that you have made stays in onBindViewholder where you call the listener at the creation of every item instead than after clicking on it.
You have simply add an onClickListener in the viewHolder.getItemView() or in a specific view of the viewholder and then perform the operation you need to do once an item is clicked.
If you set a listener inside onBindViewHolder, you also have a method called 
holder.getAdapterPosition() that you can use to understand which item are you clicking on.

The viewholder should be used only to setup the views accordingly to the data you are binding and nothing else. For this reason, you should not pass any object or listener to it and instead use the approach above.

If you have just to retrieve the selected songs after an user confirms it's playlist you can just add a public method on your adapter

```
public List<ProgramsData> getSelectedSongs()
```

that you can call from your fragment when an user click a confirm button.

In order to have a list of all selected song, you can have another list

```
ArrayList<ProgramsData> selectedPrograms;
```

that you are going to fill after the click.
The content of the listener inside the onBindViewHolder could be

```
ProgramsData currentProgram = programs.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
if(selectedPrograms.contains(currentProgram){
    selectedPrograms.remove(currentProgram);
}else{
    selectedPrograms.add(currentProgram);
}
notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition); //You can use this to update the view of the selected item
```

Then inside the onBindViewHolderMethod you can check whether the items you are binding are part of the selectedList and update the views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback method. Maintain list of selected items in array list and send back to fragment when done button is clicked or any other button you have placed for complete action.
Follow these steps

-Create an Interface with list parameter.

-Fragment should implement this interface.

-Then when you initialize Recyclerview adapter pass this interface object.

-When done is clicked call overridden method of this interface and send selected songs list as argument.